# master page in vb.net needs to be a 2 page process

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

The question is exactly as the title sounds.
I have 1 master page in asp.net(vb.net). now this master page has 1 form which has 10 textboxes in it. On the other hand the master page has about 10 different links in it (outside the form), that link to different pages.
My question is how do i keep all this same way, and only divide the form in 2 pages. 5 textboxes for first and 5 textboxes for second. So basically when master page loads, it doesnt show the 10 textboxes as original, but shows only first 5, and when clicked "continue", the next 5 textboxes load on the same place as the first 5 were. The rest of links in page and rest of the page, remains exactly the same.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 1):

A master page is used for templating.  What you do is take the "rest of links in page<sub>[sic]</sub> and rest of the page" and keep them in the master page.  But instead of you textboxes you add a content place holder to the page.  You then put two normal aspx pages in your project, and set them to fill the placeholder you just created on the master page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think you're using the term Master Page the way it should be used. A master page should hold other pages (`.master` -> `.aspx`).

Secondly, you should check out the [ASP.NET Wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163894.aspx)

Comment: i am. the thing is the links that i put in the question, is the links that open up in an contentplaceholder in the same page itself. So basically, masterpage has controls and the page that has the mster page as its placeholder is the page that loads with the link. But the form stays same on every page.